# Match fixed groups of characters space separated

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

For example, I need to match **3** groups of characters each one *space separated*, on this text:

> This is also true for humans, who can (...) hear only a limited range [12^] of sounds as well. Dogs, dolphins and other creatures can hear different frequencies than we do, for example. There is some scientific evidence our brains are receiving a much wider range of frequencies than we are able to perceive. Michael Weliky from the University of Rochester conducted a study which led him to conclude that perhaps as much as 80% of the frequencies we receive are locked in our heads, unable to be perceived.

and I found this syntax which gives me the result I want:
    `[^ ].+?(?= ).+?(?= ).+?(?= )`

but I wonder if it could be improved seems it looks quite redundant.

My [RegEx101](http://regex101.com/r/yF8fB8/3)

Comment: Do you want match things like this: `ard hgdf rid 65m`? If so, try this: `.{3}[ ]{1}`.

Comment: No, the result must be [this](http://regex101.com/r/yF8fB8/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
([^ ]+ ){2}[^ ]+
```

This gives a slightly other result, because it don't find the group of 4 words (`a much wider range`), as it does with your regex. Instead it only finds groups with three words.

Here is the **[example](http://regex101.com/r/yF8fB8/5)**

Comment: It's perfect, it divides the text into groups of n words.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the two lookaheads in the middle and replace with just the whitespace.

`[^ ].+? .+? .+?(?= )` [example](http://regex101.com/r/yF8fB8/4)

Other than that, you probably can't do match.